# Expensify Framework

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new Windows phone,We are planning to use Windows Phone Test Framework by Expensify for WP7 UI Automation.

To install this framework. What all the software things I need? . Do I need anything apart from
Windows Phone Test Framework by Expensify ,
Windows 7 OS,
Windows phone 7 SDK,
Nunit ,
Flowspec.

My another question is - can we simulate kre press or touch event using this framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special is needed apart from what you\ve mentioned.

> My another question is - can we simulate kre press or touch event using this framework.

Yes you can.

But keep in mind that Expensify framework is rather big, unfinished and i would say not very nicely written. You'd have to extend it to perform even simple operations (like clicking app bar button).